# Detecting iOS 8 Orientation change in UIView

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am detecting Regular and Compact size classes with TraitCollectionDidChange in iOS8.

I am trying to fit a particular set of data horizontally across the screen and it does not fit in Horizontal Class Regular on a Portrait iPad Mini however there would be plenty of space in Landscape.

The problem is that Horizontal SizeClass is *Regular* in Portrait and Landscape so the TraitCollectionDidChange does not fire and I don't get told about the Orientation change.

I have heard reference to `viewWillTransitionToSize` but that is not available in a UIView.

Are Apple saying they do not want UI layout diffs from Horizontal Class Regular - Portrait and Horizontal Class Regular - Landscape?

If it's OK to do it how do I get told, in a **UIView**, about the Orientation change?

Comment: I don't think it means that you should not have different layout for different orientations, but since you find the size classes too limited you can use other approaches to solve the problem (with or without size classes).

Comment: So how do I get told about the Orientation change in a UIView?

Comment: Your UIViewController gets notified about this and thus can notify its views about the new orientation.

Comment: @ott I was hoping that I wasn't going to have to do that :-)

Comment: Usually the UIView represents a state controlled by a View Controller.  Hence MVC.  Orientation should only be detected in view controller and you provide methods to call from the view controller within the UIView to change state.

Answer (score 14):

Just add the method -(void) layoutSubviews into your UIView subclass. It will get called any time the view's dimensions change. Don't forget to call [super layoutSubviews] inside your new method.

Then you can check self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass and self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass to see what you're looking at.

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    //   your code here...
}
```

Comment: This method is not called when the orientation changes, but the size is the same (i.e. from landscape right to landscape left)